# Removing from the beginning of an std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, time-complexity

I might be missing something very basic here but here is what I was wondering -

We know removing an element from the beginning of an std::vector ( vector[0] ) in C++ is an O(n) operation because all the other elements have to be shifted one place backwards.

But why isn't it implemented such that the pointer to the first element is moved one position ahead so that now the vector starts from the second element and, in essence, the first element is removed? This would be an O(1) operation.

Comment: You cannot "remove" elements form arrays. Arrays have fixed size. And who is "they" ? What you describe is something you can implement to shift elements in an array. If you refer to some specific implementation you need to say which.

Comment: *the pointer to the first element ...* What pointer to the first element? Arrays are arrays not pointers. There is no pointer that can be moved. If you want to have such a pointer in your code, then you have to write that code yourself.

Comment: I presume because "they" didn't think that'd be very useful very often, and have a lot of downsides.  Also, that it can be simulated with an array and a separate pointer to the start element within the array.  (Likewise with vector.)

Comment: Edited. I meant vector in my head.

Comment: That would require more state in the vector objects to keep track of the "actual" beginning and the beginning of the "current" first element. As well as keeping track of the "actual" capacity and the "current" capacity. More state means more complexity, and more complexity means larger changes for errors.

Comment: And if you add and remove from the beginning often, then perhaps the standard vector class isn't the right container for you? Perhaps `std::deque` instead? Or `std::list`? Or making your own container? Perhaps what you're looking for is a `std::stack` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude an especially common like-to-have are ring buffers, but they shouldn't be implemented using deletions/appendixes to std::vector, but with tricks like [MMU double-mappings](https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/2017-01-05-buffers/), pointer modulo arithmetics, or actual `std::deque<buffer_descriptor>`, where the (inefficient, because indirect) both-ended data structure is small and used to point at much larger buffers that aren't ring-wise.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number anyways, since OP has clarified the array/vector confusion in their question, let's vote to reopen.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand we could use other data structures. I was just curious if it could be optimized this way for no loss then it is no harm in doing so. As I understand now, implementing it this way would require more bookkeeping.

Comment: Because if "they" did that it would be [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::array and C-style arrays are fixed-length, and you can't change their length at all, so I think you're having a typo there and mean `std::vector` instead.

"Why was it done that way?" is a bit of a historical question. Perspectively, if your system library allowed for giving back unused memory to the operating system, your "shift backwards" trick would disallow any reuse of the former first elements' memory later on.

Also, std::vector comes from systems (like they are still basically used in every operating system) with calls like `free` and `malloc`, where you need to keep the pointer to the beginning of an allocated region around, to be able to free it later on. Hence, you'd have to lug around another pointer in the std::vector structure to be able to free the vector, and that would only be a useful thing if someone deleted from the front. And if you're deleting from the front, chances are you might be better off using a reversed vector (and delete from the end), or a vector isn't the right data structure alltogether.

Comment: *"In a vector, it's guaranteed that pointers to the nth element remain stable across all operations that do not delete the nth element. "* Removing an element already invalidates pointers to subsequent elements, so this doesn't seem like a deal breaker. The second argument is reasonable though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux hm, true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing out the typo. Could you provide some reference to understand why pointers need to remain stable?

Comment: see Francois' comment, @ritvix. For the things that *do* stay stable, cppreference.com's std::vector documentation is quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible for a vector to be implemented like that (it wouldn't be `std::vector` though). You need to keep the pointer to first element in addition to a pointer to the underlying array (alternatively some offset can be stored, but no matter how you put it you need to store more data in the vector).

Consider that this is useful only for one quite specific use-case: Erasing the first element. Well, once you got that you can also benefit while inserting an element in the front when there is free space left. If there is free space left then even inserting in the first half could benefit by shifting only the first half.

However, all this does not fit with the concept of capacity. With `std::vector` you know exactly how many elements you can add before a reallocation occurs: `capcity() - size()`. With your proposal this wouldn't hold any more. Erasing the first element would affect capacity in an odd way. It would complicate the interface and usages of vectors for all use cases.

Further, erasing elements anywhere else would still not be `O(1)`. In total it would incur a cost and add complexity for any use of the vector, while bringing an advantage only in a very narrow use case.

If you do find yourself in the situation that you need to erase the front element very often, then you can either store the vector in reverse, and erasing the last element is already `O(1)`, or use a different container.

Comment: I agree with your other points. However, can you elaborate on the capacity issue. I think relocation can be done using : `capacity() - size() - offset`. During relocation the removed elements ( offset number of elements from vector beginning ) can be ignored. I don't see why this could be an issue.

Comment: @ritvix suppose you have a vector that is full, ie `capacity() == size()`, then you remove `n` elements in the first  position. With `std::vector` you can now push `n` elements at the back without the need to reallocate or shuffle elements around. Your vector cannot do that.